# What is the most powerful server I can plug into a standard home outlet?

Tags: virtual-machine, power-supply, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, home-office

I need to run a home business, a CRM software, and other back office apps. I want to place all of these on VM's, using ESX/ESXi. (or HyperV)

Since I need SQL, and other services I need at least 128 GB of RAM.

I'm not looking for a specific hardware recommendation, rather, I'd prefer a way to search for hardware based on power consumption, adapter type, etc.

I can get a dedicated circuit breaker for this, running at 25 amps, or can install a double throw breaker for 50 amps if needed.

How can I use this information to "work backwards" and determine what hardware is appropriate?

Comment: why not run the servers in the cloud?  that way you are protected from loss of power, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, don't "work backwards" or you might end up with hardware that is a bit overkill for your purposes... It is *much* better to have 2 or 3 regular servers than try to cram everything into one monster that's a mess to maintain.

I'd start by checking the specs of a generic server, e.g. the HP ProLiant series – one of our Gen8 servers used for Hyper-V has 2×750 W power supplies (currently at 190 W total), another Gen9 one has 2×900 W, so 1800 W max. (Normally you connect both PSUs and they share the load.)

If I have my math right (please double-check), running 1 server at maximum power would need:

```
1800 W / 230 V ≈ approx. 7.8 A
1800 W / 120 V ≈ approx. 15 A
```

(In practice, your average power usage will be much lower; maybe around 300–500 watts?)

So a 25 A circuit might be useful to have (especially if you're planning to expand in the future), but is not a day-one requirement.